# csv not retaining format after splitting in R

Tags: r, csv

I have a csv file say named abc.csv where name of a column is Component.Number and there are 20 different components I'm working with. The csv file contains 2000 entries which are sorted by component number. I'm using the following code to split the csv into 20 csv files where one file contains only data corresponding to a particular Component.Number.

```
abc = read.csv("abc.csv")
for (name in levels(abc$Component.Number)){
  tmp=subset(abc,Component.Number==name)

  #Create a new filename for each Component - the folder 'skews' should already exist in the same directory
  fn=paste('skews/',gsub(' ','',name),sep='')

  #Save the CSV file containing separate expenses data for each Component
  write.table (tmp,fn,row.names=FALSE,sep = ",")
}
```

The code is working fine and I'm getting split files in the "skews" folder but the format of the files are not csv, in fact they don't have any file type. I have also tried write.csv instead of write.table in the last line, but no luck. So, how do I get the split files in .csv format and run the same R code on all of them using some kind of loop? The file names are those different component numbers. Thanks.

Comment: They are CSVs. They just don't have a file ending. Change `fn` to include `.csv`.

Comment: Just use fn=paste('skews/',gsub(' ','',name),'.csv',sep='')

Comment: Don't confuse file **type** with file **extension** <-- that's one of my pet peeves about Windows filesystems.  You can put any extension you want onto any file type without changing the contents. Then, of course Windows gets all upset because the extension doesn't match the metadata; all the OS *should* read is the metadata in the first place.